# PhoneGap/Cordova Get Number of GPS Satellites

Tags: android, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

I need to check how many GPS satellites which is connecting with device.
I know how to do that on Android native app ([how to get satellite name or number when we are getting location through GPS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753069/how-to-get-satellite-name-or-number-when-we-are-getting-location-through-gps-in)).

But, I need how to do that in phonegap/cordova hybrid application.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the number of satellites? Normaly the geolocation plugin asks for GPS provider and a network provider everytime you call `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` or `watchPosition()`

Comment: Thanks Sithys, I know geolocation plugin (Im using it), but there is no Satellites number in result http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Comment: geolocation plugin doesn't provide that information, you'll have to create your own plugin for that

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I need to creare own plugin to do this.

Comment: why do you need the number of satellites?

Comment: That's just my customer's requirement, I dont know why they need it ^^

Answer (score 2):

There is not anything developed to achieve that. If you want, you should make a plugin based in that android functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since ios does not provide the number of satellites, and since phone gap is  designed as a subset of functionality that runs on all phoneplattform, the num satellites is not available.
Further today the number of satellites is of little use, today phones use at least a combination of the US GPS and the Russion GLONASS. Thus always having many satellites in view, even in urban canyons.

You cannot use the num of satellites as a quality indicator.
Use horicontal acuracy estimate for that purpose. 
Both android and ios provide that (check if phone gap provides, this, too)

Comment: that ios doesn't provide that information doesn't mean android can't, there are a lot of things on plugins that are different on ios and android. In this case the number of satellites isn't available on the android version of the plugin, but could be done with a new plugin

Comment: @jcesarmobile I removed the "not possible".